# What is the purpose of Shadari in a temple?

Tags: temple, practice

I have heard that the Shadari is a symbolism of God's feet (patham) and he blesses you when it is kept over your head. I am not certain if this is correct, if someone could explain in detail it would be enlightening.

Comment: Note that Sadagopam and Sadagopuram are just different words for Sadari.

Comment: @Keshav Thanks for pointing out. Your answer was helpful.